# Access - GUID value stored in textbox, can't be used in SELECT statements

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that can be called from a number of places. So I'm using openargs to pull the value over that I need. That value is a GUID. When the open form command is issued, I use `stringfromguid(parameter)` to pass the GUID along. I tried without the stringfromguid() and that didn't work for anything. The value is stored in a hidden control on the form. It ends up having a value like `{guid {753DA23E-D9B5-4570-BFD8-30F7B9B4F450}}` which is the correct GUID.

However, when I try to use that value in any further select statements (setting the record source on a subform in this instance) it doesn't work. I know the select statement works, I can copy and paste it in manually but use `'xxx'` where `xxx` in the `753...F450`portion of the value and it works. So, I know that:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE IDcol = '753DA23E-D9B5-4570-BFD8-30F7B9B4F450'
```

pulls what I want. But not matter what I do, various stringfromguid() or guidfromstring() attempts, it doesn't work. It ends up trying to use

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE IDcol = {guid {753DA23E-D9B5-4570-BFD8-30F7B9B4F450}}
```

Which doesn't evalueate to anything.

The data is hosted on a SQL 2012 server. Access is just the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me - using an Access table:

```
SELECT 
    GuidField As GuidKey, 
    GuidField As GuidText, 
    [Code]
FROM 
    tblGuid
WHERE
    GuidField = {guid {D8A01BE9-2387-452A-9CF4-30A970E0F078}} 
    AND 
    GuidField = GUIDFromString("{D8A01BE9-2387-452A-9CF4-30A970E0F078}")
```

So either method for filtering should work. And no matter what ODBC driver you use, as Access has been able to handle GUIDs since version 95.

[image]

To strip a text Guid:

```
' Private constants.
'
' Length of GUID string per definition.
Private Const GuidLength    As Integer = 38
' Converted Access Guid header.
Private Const GuidHeader    As String = "{guid "
' Lenght of Access Guid header.
Private Const HeaderLength  As Integer = 6

Public Sub StripTextGuidHeader(ByRef TextGuid As String)

    Const Start As Integer = 1 + HeaderLength

    If InStr(TextGuid, GuidHeader) = 1 Then
        ' This is a converted byte Guid:
        ' "{guid {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}}"
        ' Strip the header and the trailing curly bracket.
        TextGuid = Mid(TextGuid, Start, GuidLength)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When I do an Access query with `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE IDcol = {guid {753DA23E-D9B5-4570-BFD8-30F7B9B4F450}}` i get no results, but when I do `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE IDcol = '753DA23E-D9B5-4570-BFD8-30F7B9B4F450'` I get results.

Comment: Well, if so, the ODBC driver simply converts the Guid to text. Should be simple to manage, so what is your trouble really?

Comment: Problem is the value is passed and stored as `{guid {753DA23E-D9B5-4570-BFD8-30F7B9B4F450}}`. I can use MID to extract it, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution designed for handling GUIDs. If not, I'll go ahead with MID.

Comment: I see. I use a subfunction for this. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Hey @Gustav thanks for this. It may not be pretty but it solved a problem that's been beating me for hours